# Cargar variable de env cuando inicio proyecto en ReactJS

Tags: reactjs

Tengo la siguiente duda que lo logre encontrar correctamente o un buen ejemplo en la documentación:

Estoy trabajando con un proyecto en ReactJS utilizando `create react app` en el cual el mismo provee dos script `react-scripts start` para modo desarrollo y `react-scripts build` para realizar el build para producción.

Manejo 3 entornos en los proyectos que trabajo: local, test, y producción.

Dentro del proyecto tengo un archivo `.env` donde cargo ciertas variables de entorno, cuando necesito compilar para test o producción tengo que cambiar una variable que se llama `REACT_APP_APP_ENV`. Mi pregunta es la siguiente:

¿Cómo puedo hacer para pasar por parámetro, con alguna bandera, para que yo no tenga que estar cambiando dentro del .env, sino que yo tenga 6 scripts en total?

Doy ejemplo:

```json
"scripts": {
        "start": "react-scripts start",
        "build": "react-scripts build",
    },
```

Asi lo tengo actualmente

```json
"scripts": {
        "start": "react-scripts start",
        "build": "react-scripts build",
        "start:test": "react-scripts start",
        "build:test": "react-scripts build",
        "start:prod": "react-scripts start",
        "build:prod": "react-scripts build",
    },
```

La idea seria agregar 2 script por cada entorno, y que cada script lo que haga sea cargar la variable dentro de los `env` del proyecto.

Muchas gracias!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Instala en tu proyecto como dependencia de desarrollo el paquete `env-cmd` usando el comando `npm install --save-dev env-cmd`.
2. Crea los diferentes archivos `.env` que necesites colocando al final el nombre del ambiente de trabajo deseado. Por ejemplo:

   - Archivo `.production.env`

   ```
   REACT_APP_APP_ENV="PRODUCTION"
   ```

   - Archivo `.development.env`

   ```
   REACT_APP_APP_ENV="DEVELOPMENT"
   ```

   - Archivo `.testing.env`

   ```
   REACT_APP_APP_ENV="TESTING"
   ```
3. Coloca en el `package.json` los scripts correspondientes especificando antes de cada comando el ambiente de trabajo:

```
"scripts": {
        "start": "env-cmd -f .development.env react-scripts start",
        "build": "env-cmd -f .development.env react-scripts build",
        "start:test": "env-cmd -f .testing.env react-scripts start",
        "build:test": "env-cmd -f .testing.env react-scripts build",
        "start:prod": "env-cmd -f .production.env react-scripts start",
        "build:prod": "env-cmd -f .production.env react-scripts build",
},
```

Si lo prefieres, para tenerlo todo más organizado, crea una carpeta `enviroment` y coloca dentro todas los archivos `.env`. Luego simplementes especificas la ruta relativa como `env-cmd -f ./enviroment/.development.env`

---

La forma que te adjunté es la más flexible de todas y te permite personalizar tus entornos a tu gusto, incluso crear todos los que quieras. No obstante, `react-scripts` [busca por defecto](https://create-react-app.dev/docs/adding-custom-environment-variables/#what-other-env-files-can-be-used) un archivo específico en tu entorno según el **comando** que ejecutes. Por ejemplo:

- `"react-scripts start"` buscará por defecto en tu entorno de trabajo por orden `.env.development.local`, `.env.local`, `.env.development`, `.env`.
- `"react-scripts build"` buscará por defecto en tu entorno de trabajo por orden  `.env.production.local`, `.env.local`, `.env.production`, `.env`
- `"react-scripts test"`: buscará por defecto en tu entorno de trabajo por orden`.env.test.local`, `.env.test`, `.env`.

Comment: Perdon la demora.
Con la ultima descripcion que mencias, no hace falta instalar `env-cm` utilizando el nombre de los archivos .env correctamente funciona. no?

Comment: @GonzaloPiñeiro con la última descripción no hace falta instalar nada, pero ten en cuenta que dependerá del comando que le pases a react-scripts, por tanto, no es tan personalizable como lo puede ser con env-cmd. De cualquier manera, toma la que mas se ajuste a tus requerimientos.